# NFSS error when trying to use »kpfonts«

Tags: fonts

I'm having some trouble trying to use kpfonts. [I'm using a Linux system, with TexLive2010.] I copied the kpfonts files to my local texmf directory as per the instructions, and then ran

```
 updmap --enable Map=kpfonts.map
```

That seemed to work properly. 
But when I try to use kpfonts in a document I get the following error:

```
ERROR: LaTeX Error: This NFSS system isn't set up properly.

--- TeX said ---

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.5 \begin{document}

--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

For encoding scheme OML the defaults jkp/m/it do not form a valid font shape
```

Minimal document I'm working on:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[veryoldstyle]{kpfonts}
\begin{document}
This is a test. Duct, dust, and so forth.
\end{document}
```

Web searches haven't turned up any solutions; has anyone got any idea about what might be wrong?

Comment: Just to check: you downloaded texlive 2010 from the tug website and installed it that way? If it's a version of texlive packaged in a flavour of linux like ubuntu, it won't be 2010. Why didn't you install kpfonts through tlmgr?

Comment: For some reason, when I first went to tlmgr, I couldn't find kpfonts. But I checked again now, and it's there....  So it looks like I just made extra work for myself before.  Thanks!

Comment: If it's on CTAN, it should be possible to install it through tlmgr. I'd try hard to avoid installing packages manually unless you really need to.

Comment: Seamus - me too. And I was surprised when I couldn't find it at first.

Answer (score 2):

try this: `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=kpfonts.map` if you installed TeX Live as root.

Comment: `LaTeX Error: This NFSS system isn't set up properly.` is a latex error. It indicates a bug in the package (in this case one that has been corrected already). It has nothing to do with map-files.

Comment: I actually had tried      sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=kpfonts.map after I couldn't get it to work the first time (though I hadn't installed TeX Live as root), and got the same error.  Installing for tlmgr as Seamus suggested worked [again, I don't know why I couldn't find it in tlmgr the first time I looked.]. Thanks all.